# Can't set / update IFS variable in Bash on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, bash

I'm having trouble setting the `IFS` variable in Bash. I'm running Mac OS X 10.11.2 El Capitan and am using iTerm2. The same behavior occurred in the out-of-box Terminal app though.

What could possibly be causing this?

[image]

**UPDATE**: Here is a screenshot of the same thing on separate lines. I thought that adding the `hexdump` command to the pipeline would clearly show that it wasn't working properly, but perhaps not. I'm still pretty new to Bash.

[image]

Comment: Nothing special about IFS -- you'd see the exact same behavior trying to set a variable in the same command as you print its value with *any* variable name.

Comment: ...which is to say: Your code is successfully setting an environment variable `IFS` to `,` in the scope of the echo command, but the command's arguments are expanded *before* that takes place (so you aren't changing its arguments), and `echo` doesn't look at its environment variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to set IFS on the same line as your echo.  Do it on a separate line, as you did with `Name`.  Also, since IFS is the characters you declare to be white space, you'll need quotes in the `echo` command:

```
IFS=','
echo "$IFS"
```

Comment: Even if I do it on a different line, it still fails. I'll post another screenshot.

Comment: @TrevorSullivan, you also **must** use quotes, as Stephen does here!

Comment: @TrevorSullivan, ...without the quotes, the results of the expansion are string-split -- split into separate strings *whenever any character in $IFS exists*; since `$IFS` contains no characters not found in `$IFS`, `echo $IFS` is thus precisely the same as `echo`, whereas `echo "$IFS"` preserves them.

Comment: Yep, my new screenshot shows it with single quotes.

Comment: @TrevorSullivan, no, quotes **on the `echo` line**.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I'm pretty sure I saw your name in another StackOverflow post that I found while trying to research this topic, before posting my own question about it, haha.

Comment: Oh, I see now. That makes sense. You're right. It's working now.

Answer (score 1):

If you set it within its own command, it works fine:

```
$ IFS=, ; echo $IFS
,
```

You're best off doing this in a subshell or in a script, though, as that way you won't lose the original setting in your working shell:

```
$ ( IFS=, ; echo $IFS )
,
```

Comment: I tried to be clear that my objections are respecting what you imply, not what you say. Putting the first two sentences in your answer directly next to each other implies a causal relationship.

Comment: Restating with thinko corrected: The way you write this implies that it's only *because* `IFS` is a special shell variable that the OP's code doesn't work; that's not an accurate implication: Putting the assignment in the same simple command as the `echo` wouldn't work with *any* variable.

Comment: Good point @CharlesDuffy, I have removed the incorrect implication.